# SVG Circle not animated in Edge

Tags: animation, svg, microsoft-edge, svg-animate

The below svg animates perfectly in all browsers but Edge (surprise!).

```
<svg width="80" height="24" viewBox="0 0 120 30" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="#555">
    <circle cx="15" cy="15" r="15">
        <animate attributeName="r" from="15" to="15"
                 begin="0s" dur="0.8s"
                 values="15;9;15" calcMode="linear"
                 repeatCount="indefinite" />
        <animate attributeName="fill-opacity" from="1" to="1"
                 begin="0s" dur="0.8s"
                 values="1;.5;1" calcMode="linear"
                 repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </circle>

</svg>
```

I tried adding `px` as units but no luck.

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: It really is a suprprise because the up to date edge is using the same rendering engine as chrome. So if it works in chrome it also works in current edge version.

Comment: @cloned, just checked: in FF and Chrome animates like a charm, in edge build 18362 the svg is dead still

Comment: It should work (https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-smil). Make sure that you have the new Edge (with the wave logo), not the old Edge (with the blue "e" logo).  Old Edge did not support SVG SMIL animation elements.

Comment: well I can not "make sure" about anything, as those are clients' browsers and I can not control them. My own edge version is this `Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0`

Comment: https://leunen.me/fakesmile/faq.html allows Edge to support SMIL since it has no native support.

Comment: @RobertLongson the animations on https://leunen.me/fakesmile/index.html in edge do not move...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comments and answers I decided to go for clear CSS animation, instead of SVG. I grabbed the code from https://projects.lukehaas.me/css-loaders/ and my "solution" looks like this:

```
<style>
.loader,
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 2.2em;
  height: 2.2em;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  -webkit-animation: load7 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: load7 1.3s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.loader {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 80px auto;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
  animation-delay: -0.16s;
}
.loader:before,
.loader:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.loader:before {
  left: -3.5em;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
  animation-delay: -0.32s;
}
.loader:after {
  left: 3.5em;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.2em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.2em 0 0;
  }
}
@keyframes load7 {
  0%,
  80%,
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.2em 0 -1.3em;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 2.2em 0 0;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I try to check your code and refer to the MDN documentation.

I can see that you are using **animate, attributeName, from, to, dur** attributes in your code.

**Animate** is supported in Edge version <=79.

Whereas compatibility is unknown for **attributeName, from, to, dur**

[image]

Reference:

[SVG Animate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate)

I think this is the reason why your code is not working in the MS edge legacy browser.

I suggest you recommend your clients use the MS Edge Chromium browser or you can remove the animation or show the image in place of animation to avoid the issue.